# Kotlin elvis operator fallback for any case of null in function call chain

Tags: kotlin

I would like to know if the `?:` elvis operator is called if one of following function calls is returning `null`.

```
  private fun extractProductAttributes(productEntity: JSONObject): List<JSONObject> {
        return productEntity.optJSONObject("Entity")
                ?.optJSONObject("Attributes")
                ?.optJSONArray("Attribute")
                ?.toList() as List<JSONObject>
                ?: listOf()
    }
```

If any of those functions is returning `null` I'd like to fallback to an empty immutable list.
Is this working like expected?

Comment: Probably calling `emptyList()` as last operation conveys the intention a little better than `listOf` with empty parameters.

Comment: @Burdui `listOf` with no elements gets resolved to `emptyList`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it will. Let's break down the code to see how it works...

Suppose, you have this code,

```
a?.b?.c ?: d
```

If either of `a`, `a.b`, or `a.b.c` is null, then `d` is returned.

Refs:

- https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#safe-calls
- https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#elvis-operator

---

On a side note, you need to use a safe cast here.

```
productEntity.optJSONObject("Entity")
                ?.optJSONObject("Attributes")
                ?.optJSONArray("Attribute")
                ?.toList() as? List<JSONObject>
                ?: listOf()
```

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I forgot to remove the cast from that block of code. But as you have added `?` to `as?`, wouldn't that change the return type to be nullable?

Comment: If the cast fails and returns `null`, then it'd chain over to the `?:` and return an empty list. This would only ever happen if the list is not a `List<JSONObject>`, for example if the returned object was `null`. I think I avoided a ClassCastException here (casting nullable list to non-null List type).